# Add component to title bar of TitleWindow

Tags: flash-builder

i work with flash builder 4.6, and i try to add Maximize/Minimize button in title bar of titlewindow component. i remember in last version of flash existed a title bar component but in new version i don't found it!!

if someone know the way to add the component in title bar, or know a better way to maximize/minimize a titlewindow, thanks to sharing.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have always just used resizableTitleWindow. You can find it here:

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=1207017